# Angular2 library bundle for debug

Tags: javascript, angular, requirejs, systemjs

We have an Angular2 application with systemjs. We want to debug it in the browser. If we start the application in Chrome, start the debugger, then it is working fine. One problem is, systemjs is loading all the scripts (cca 530). We want to bundle @angular/* and load it as one script with all dependencies. We can bundle the whole application into one javascript file, but this is not good for debugging.

We do NOT want to bundle the whole application and then debug it, because compiling and bundling is just slow (couple of seconds).

How to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to bundle `@angular/*` in one file?

Comment: Because I do not want to load 500x javascript files, it loads 20sec.

Comment: Are you using typescript for angular2 development?

Comment: Yes, we are using Typescript.

Comment: Use bundled UMD js for the packages whenever possible. It's not nearly as bad as that. See official Angular plunk, http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue